# What does this piece of perl code mean?

Tags: perl

I'm dealing with a Perl script. Perl is quite new to me. 
Does anybody have an idea what this code does?

```
$pval = sprintf("%0.1e", Statistics::Distributions::uprob($z));
```

Where      :

```
my $z= ($all{key} - $mu) / ${sigma};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$pval` is assigned a formatted string in the shape of a floating-point number in scientific notation. Presumably the function `uprob` from the Statistics module returns such a number.

`$z` is passed as argument to that function, and it seems to be a number calculated from a value in the hash `%all` with the key `key`, minus `$mu`, divided by `$sigma`. Pretty straightforward.

Comment: @Bfu38 You're welcome.. don't forget to accept if you feel the answer is satisfactory.